# How to using oracle distinct and order siblings by at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle

the distinct broken the order siblings by,how can i use them at the same time?
such as
select distinct * from table xxx starts with ... connect by id=pid  order siblings by field
here is the test sqls executed with different results

```
select distinct * from test_table start with pid is null connect by prior id=pid order siblings by order_num;

select * from test_table start with pid is null connect by prior id=pid order siblings by order_num;
```

here is the table

```
create table TEST_TABLE(id NUMBER,pid NUMBER,order_num NUMBER);
insert into TEST_TABLE (id, pid, order_num) values (1, null, 1);
insert into TEST_TABLE (id, pid, order_num) values (2, 1, 5);
insert into TEST_TABLE (id, pid, order_num) values (3, null, 2);
insert into TEST_TABLE (id, pid, order_num) values (4, 1, 4);
insert into TEST_TABLE (id, pid, order_num) values (5, 3, 2);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; a complete query that we can execute; and the expected output for that query. It is very difficult to answer an abstract question as we have to guess at a concrete example that demonstrates the problem and hope that it matches what you are thinking of; if **YOU** provide that example (in a format that we can copy/paste and execute) then you will get an answer to the question you want answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` in an inner query and then use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to find the duplicates in an outer query and maintain the order using `ORDER BY ROWNUM` in that outer query:

```sql
SELECT id, pid, order_num
FROM   (
  SELECT id, pid, order_num,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, pid, order_num ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT id, pid, order_num
    FROM   test_table
    START WITH pid IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = pid
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY order_num
  )
  ORDER BY ROWNUM
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table TEST_TABLE(id,pid,order_num) AS
SELECT 1, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: this has an added row so there is a path back to a previous branch in the hierarchy to create duplicate rows in the output.*

Outputs:

> | ID | PID | ORDER_NUM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | *null* | 1 |
> | 4 | 1 | 4 |
> | 2 | 1 | 5 |
> | 3 | *null* | 2 |
> | 5 | 3 | 2 |
> | 1 | 5 | 5 |

and maintains the order of the siblings from the hierarchical query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=309c363be033add982b4c917e335c28f)*

Comment: I'm sorry about that,the duplicate is not in the init table. It happend when the connect by prior id=pid,  I'll show you the sample data later

Comment: I'm sorry,you're right.the init table has repeat records....just distinct it then do the connect

Comment: @JokerSora You can get duplicates in the output without having duplicates in the input when you have multiple branches merging (I've updated the answer to your sample data with an added row that demonstrates that case) so you still may need to filter for duplicates afterwards. However, if your problem was duplicates in the input data then, yes, just use `DISTINCT` first and then generate the hierarchy afterwards.